# What is the expected value of a $n$-sided fair die, but each side value is chosen at random?

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

My question is this:

> Given that each side of a $n$-sided fair die ($n>1$) is labelled a number from $1$ to $k$ ($k>1$) at random, what is the expected value after a single roll of this die?

I honestly don't have much clue as to how to start with this. I have tried some example values for $n$ and $k$ (very small, like $n=3$, $k=2$), but I haven't developed a suitable strategy for the more generalized problem. Could someone give some pointers as to how to go about this problem? Thanks.

So I will show my attempt for $n=3$, $k=2$ below:

If I have the faces to be 1,1,1, then then expected value for this specific assignment will obviously be 1. There is a $1/8$ chance to get this assignment, so $1\cdot1/8=1/8$.

Then for 1,1,2, we have that the expected value is $\frac23\cdot1+\frac13\cdot2=\frac43$. There are $3$ possible ways to get 1,1,2 (1,1,2; 1,2,1; 2,1,1), so the final value is $\frac38\cdot\frac43=\frac12$.

For 1,2,2, we have that the expected value is $\frac23\cdot2+\frac13\cdot1=\frac53$. There are $3$ possible ways to get this, so the final value is $\frac38\cdot\frac53=\frac58$.

Finally, for 2,2,2, we have that the expected value is 2, and there is only one possible way to get this assignment, so $2\cdot\frac18=\frac14$.

Final answer: $\frac18+\frac12+\frac58+\frac14=\frac{12}8=\frac32$.

Comment: It's the expected average value of the sides, which is the average expected value of the sides, which is $\frac{k+1}{2}$.

Comment: Try it for $n=2$ to get insight.

Comment: Take another look at Qiaochu Yuan's comment.  This means that the value of $n$ is **totally irrelevant**.